# How can I tail the GCP logs with HTTP without missing log entries?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am writing a CLI to tail the GCP logs.

I am using the HTTP GET method to read the logs here:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

**Issue**: There are log entries missing.

When using pagination (using pageToken and nextPageToken) and constantly polling the last page I can get the latest records. This is fine when the log-write-rate is low.

But when the log-write-rate is high, there are log entries missing using this polling technique.

If I query the same time period but in the past, those missing log entries show up.

It seems that at a certain log-write-rate the GCP logging server will leave out some log entries from pagination pages, seemingly skipping over them and never including them again in the same series of paginated pages.

This is an issue as I could be polling for a particular log query but the result set is incomplete as log entries on the leading edge of time are randomly missing.

**Question**: What is the correct way to poll this end point without missing log entires when they are being written at a high rate?

Comment: IIRC logs are posted asynchronously which means a polling application might not see all logs at the current polling time. After a settlement period missing log entries should be there. Edit your post and include the code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, do you know how long the settlement period is? The code is quite long and it would need to include the concurrent writers too. But it is as described - polling the HTTP GET endpoint with the `pageToken` pagination misses log entries that are being written at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember the details with certainty nor do I have a document reference. This was from a conversation with one of the Google engineers on the StackDriver team.

Comment: You can configure [Logsink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#sinks)to store the logs and display them as needed by using filters. Ensure there is at least one sink used to export copies of log entries available within your project. As Cloud Logging service receives log entries, they are compared against each sink. If a log entry matches a sink object query, then a copy of the log entry is written to the sink's export destination. You can export copies of your logs outside of Cloud Logging using [log sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2).

Comment: @zino, Have you tried configuring Log sinks. Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @Srividya Thanks, I know about log sinks, I specifically wanted to avoid them to avoid the costs of data transfer and storage, and also want to use a local SQLite database to query the JSON based logs.

Comment: Using SQLite changes your question. Your question is about tailing logs, not storing logs in a database. Focus on one problem at a time.